# How to count values in a column that come after a particular value

Tags: postgresql

I have a column that has two types of values A or B. I need to find the count of values that come after the first occurrence of A.
eg

```
column
B
B
B
A
B
A
B
```

The result in this case would be 4 as their are 4 entries after the first occurrence of A(including A)

Comment: What do you mean by "after"? How are the rows ordered?

Comment: Order by a sequence column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub query to get the id number (of whatever column you are using to order the columns) of the first 'A'.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t (
>     id serial,
>     col char(1));
> insert into t (col) values
> ('B'),
> ('B'),
> ('A'),
> ('B'),
> ('A'),
> ('B')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

6 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select 
>   count(*) NUM
> from t
> where id >= 
> (select MIN(id) 
> from t 
> where col = 'A');
> ```
>
> ```
> | num |
> | --: |
> |   4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=87def9945450fd1c61e3f4c4030691a0)*